# Generate bitstream without vendor specific IDE

Tags: fpga, xilinx, xilinx-ise, xilinx-edk

What I am trying to achieve is to synthesize very simplistic `vhdl` to `bitstream` and test on a `proto` board.

Actually language does not matter. Anyone achieved so far so that you can directly generate bit from any form of code without the requirement of running vendor specific IDE’s ?

I stumbled upon within my search-foo skills but wanted to ask you guys before I desperately give each option a try unless someone reports success with some of the options.

I know this can be done because I compiled and synthed `petalinux` from scratch and got a fully functional `bitstream`.
Now I am just trying to experiment on simplistic approaches.

Comment: Why don't you want to use vendor specific IDEs?

Comment: How did you compiled and synthed petalinux from scratch without importing a Vivado hdf file?

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about fpga configuration bistream, then building it without vendor tools is only possible if you have the knowledge of the hardware that will consume that bitstream. The major vendors won't release the knowledge about their fpga internals, so building configuration bistream is not really feasible.

There are open source projects aiming at reverse engineering some simplest fpga and providing tools, but so far I'm only aware of IceStorm, targeting Lattice iCE40 family of fpga.

Comment: See [PetaLinux Gentting Started](http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/PetaLinux+Getting+Started) **Tools Installation & Setup**
"The Xilinx Vivado (with SDK) and PetaLinux tools and BSPs must be installed prior to any design development." Check out the **XilinxTools Design Flow**. You've apparently missed the distinction between not using an IDE and not using a vendor's tools. While you might ask if *Anyone achieved so far so that you can directly generate bit from any form of code without the requirement of running vendor specific IDE’s ?* is clear or useful, IceStorm doesn't support Xilinx devices.

Comment: If you have an operating system and a compiler-linker chain then your setup is compatible with any fpga vendor for development. It’s only a matter of know how and resources.